# Python while loop user input until result found in sql

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, while-loop

I would like for my code to ask the user to enter user ID. If User ID is found in the SQL database, the system would print successful. Otherwise, it would keep asking the user to enter user ID. Right now, if I type a valid user ID first (U0020), the code runs fine.

Problem is, if I type in the wrong user ID first (ewehri), even if I key in a valid user ID afterwards, the output is still "Sorry, no such record in the database. Please try again" and prompts for user input again. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

First, I define calling sql database to get account number from user ID:

```
conn=create_connection()
def getacct(userid): 
    query = """\
        select Account_Number
        from User_Account
        where UserID = '{}'
        """ .format(userid)

    return (execute_read_query (conn, query))
```

This works fine. After which, I do this to put the results into a list:

```
userid = input("Please enter your user id:")
acct_no = getacct(userid)

accountno = []
for i in acct_no:
    accountno.append(i[0])
```

Then comes the problematic part. I check if the list [accountno] is empty. If it is empty, that means the User ID is not in database and hence could not return any account number. If it is not empty, then it should print "successful" and exits the loop. However, as mentioned, it would not exit the loop.

```
def User():
    while accountno:
        print("successful")
        break
    else:
        print ("Sorry, no such record in the database. Please try again")
        userid = input("Please enter your user id:")
```

I also tried many iterations of this code like placing the "put result in list" part of the code inside def User(), or this:

```
def User():
    while not accountno:
        print ("Sorry, no such record in the database. Please try again")
        userid = input("Please enter your user id:")
        
        if accountno:
            print ("Successful!")
```

and really much more but I just can't get the output I need. I'm hoping someone here would know what I did wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code you have does not do anything to delete the bad info. Therefore the while loop condition always returns True and runs forever. How do you need to process the numbers in `accountno`? Do you pop and use them or just print successful? If all you need to do is print 'successful', then delete the code, try `del accountno[0]`

Comment: If you need to delete from the end, do `accountno.pop()` instead.

Comment: @anvoice I need to use it. Just printing "successful" for now so that it is easier to pinpoint errors since I make a lot. I'm quite unfamiliar with python. May I know where in my code should I use `accountno.pop()`?

Comment: Let me write this as an answer. This is taking more space than anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accountno.pop()`. right after the `if accountno`. By using the pop method instead of del, you can use the value later, e.g. `saveUserID = accountno.pop()`. An alternative is to use a break statement right after the `print("Successful")` part. However, another of your issues is that you don't append the userid to `accountno`, but use the if to check `accountno`, not `userid` for the new input. Finally, you should pass `accountno` as a function argument to `User()` and use it as a return type. Here is a better example:

```
def User(userid):
    while not userid:
        print ("Sorry, no such record in the database. Please try again")
        userid = input("Please enter your user id:")

    print ("Successful!")
    return userid
```

This way your `accountno` variable will contain a single successfully entered userid. Your print should come after the while loop since it prints only upon success anyway.

To use then, say something like:

```
accountno.append(User(accountno))
```